# Uppercases convert to lowercase when loading a file with h5py

Tags: python-3.x, lowercase, h5py

Hello I can't load a hdf5 file with h5py:

```
$ python verif.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "verif.py", line 4, in <module>
    h5f = h5py.File("../DeepFISH-Github_projects/DeepFISH/dataset/'+'LowRes_13434_overlapping_pairs.h5",'r')
  File "/home/jeanpat/VirtualEnv/venv3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/h5py/_hl/files.py", line 272, in __init__
    fid = make_fid(name, mode, userblock_size, fapl, swmr=swmr)
  File "/home/jeanpat/VirtualEnv/venv3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/h5py/_hl/files.py", line 92, in make_fid
    fid = h5f.open(name, flags, fapl=fapl)
  File "h5py/_objects.pyx", line 54, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper (/tmp/pip-at6d2npe-build/h5py/_objects.c:2684)
  File "h5py/_objects.pyx", line 55, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper (/tmp/pip-at6d2npe-build/h5py/_objects.c:2642)
  File "h5py/h5f.pyx", line 76, in h5py.h5f.open (/tmp/pip-at6d2npe-build/h5py/h5f.c:1930)
OSError: Unable to open file (Unable to open file: name = '../deepfish-github_projects/deepfish/dataset/'+'lowres_13434_overlapping_pairs.h5', errno = 2, error message = 'no such file or directory', flags = 0, o_flags = 0
```

The string containing the path to the file:

```
../DeepFISH-Github_projects/DeepFISH/dataset'+'LowRes_13434_overlapping_pairs.h5
```

seems to be modified by h5py

```
 ../deepfish-github_projects/deepfish/dataset/lowres_13434_overlapping_pairs.h5
```

I could modify the directory name, but it's weird.

Answer (score 1):

In this line

```
h5f = h5py.File("../DeepFISH-Github_projects/DeepFISH/dataset/'+'LowRes_13434_overlapping_pairs.h5",'r')
```

you're trying to open a file with a literal `'+'` in its name. The outer quotes are double quotes, so the single quotes within the string are just part of the name. What you probably wanted to use is:

```
h5f = h5py.File("../DeepFISH-Github_projects/DeepFISH/dataset/" + "LowRes_13434_overlapping_pairs.h5",'r')
```

I don't know why the error message is all lower case, maybe the library tries to find the file in a case insensitive way if it doesn't find it by the original name, or the underlying file system is case insensitive and this is just how the OS reports the missing file error.